# How to pull down Nexus OSS repo files with a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml, nexus

I'm trying to replicate a Jenkins production need in my lab, and it involves fetching/pulling files from Github & Nexus 2, building with ant/gradle, then publishing to Nexus. The Github part is working fine in my Jenkins pipeline, but I'm having some issues with the syntax/reqs for Nexus. I installed Nexus OSS in my lab to duplicate Nexus 2's functionality. I am able to upload files manually to the repo using curl, and I'm sure I can use it to download as well. This doesn't seem like the best or most efficient option however, if there will be multiple files.

I keep seeing references to Maven/pom.xml on all my searches for this topic, but I can't find a good primer on how to use them in this context. Would a pom.xml file be the best option for 
this Jenkins/Nexus configuration and the requirements? Also, how close are Nexus 2/3 in functionality to Nexus OSS? Will I be able to port over the code for use with nexus 2 fairly easily?

Comment: This isn't necessarily off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you might have better luck getting an answer on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @chb when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Point well-taken. Given the temptation of casting a wider net, it might be better to refrain from this type of suggestion altogether.

Comment: @gnat just saw my x-posted thread got locked in Software Engineering. Will avoid cross posting in the future